# Debugging in Dev-C++ makes IDE crash and not respond

Tags: c, debugging, ide

I'd love to ask someone to hint me what to do. I have installed Dev-C++ on my computer (the 5.11 ver.)
I don't know what happened to it, if it's Windows 8.1 problem or some other I really don't know, but when I start to debug, it simply stops working.
What exactly happens:
I open dev-c++, then I open my *.c file. I set a breakpoint in my source code, and when I hit debug, a pop-up windows shows:

```
You have not enabled debugging info (-g) and/or stripped it from executable (-s) in Compiler Options.
Do you want to correct this now?
```

And when I hit yes, it simply stops to respond, and crashes.
I have never occured such situation, because on every computer I have worked, I'd got no problem with debugging on Dev-C++. Even running it in compatibility mode didn't help. 
I really don't know what to do. For any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: a possible workaround (I will not get into what I think of windows 8.x)  add the '-g' to the compile and link options

Answer (score 15):

**For me to fix by following as below**

1. Go to Tools -> Compiler option
2. Change from **TMD-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit Release** to **TMD-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit Debug**
3. Put the option -g as in the picture [image]
4. Then click OK and run again!
5. Hope it will help!

Comment: Why is this necessary with Dev-C++ 5.11?

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. GO to Tools > Compiler Option >
2. On select Compiler Set to Configure >> TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64 bit **Debug**
3. Now in general tap space put -g
4. **Most Important** : Rebuild All (F12) **

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools => Compiler options.
Then select TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-BIT DEBUG
Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open File -> New -> Project -> Console Application or Empty project
2. Write a project_name and select **OK** button
   [image: sample_project]
3. write your code and Save as main.c in the same folder you saved you .dev file
   [image]
4. add watcher any line you want and debug it.

Thats all. You don't need to add any parameter to anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set up your compiler property by adding -g to both commands fields. Here is a YouTube video shows you how to do that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOnl-Ojd66Q

I'm also using window 8, and after following the video, I still got the same pop up widow with the same message. I found out if you click no for  "Do you want to correct this now" the debugger will start working. I don't know why, but it works for me.  Good luck!

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create a project; then copy your code into the project; set the following compiler option: settings tab -> code generation : disable all optimizations and finally settings tab -> linker: set to yes the generating debugging information and the strip executable choices. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

a) Tools -> Compiler Options.

b) Put `-g` in both boxes of the compiler tab.

c) Make sure both the boxes with "Add the following...." are checked and then hit ok.

Answer (score 0):

adding the -g manually did not work for me.

This is what worked for me :

As other said, you have to create a new **PROJECT**, then paste your old code into it.
after that, just press the debugger button as you would, it will ask to put the -g for you, and this time when you say YES, it will not crash. It will work as a charm.

Watch this video to clarify :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFpShi0yAc4

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem when I ran my Program **without compiling**.
That was only the reason for this crashes and errors for me.

Dev-C++ IDE requires compilation first then after it allows to run the program unlike other IDE like C-Free which automatically compiles first and run the program for you.

Use **F11** shortcut key for compile and run the program for Dev-C++ IDE.

It works for me.