# Why doesn't my Dev C++ terminal window take inputs when I try to debug

Tags: c, debugging, terminal, dev-c++

[program ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYzwR.png)

I tried to debug this program but when I open the terminal window to give inputs, it doesn't take any inputs. It is like the keyboard doesn't work but the window takes inputs just fine when I execute a program normally, this only happens when I try debug a program. Please, help me out!

Edit: my IDE doesn't crash, everything is fine except the terminal window doesn't display or take any of my inputs.
eg: 'Input an integer:' and when i try to input an integer, it doesn't take it or display it on the screen. I have noticed that also it takes longer to close the terminal window when I try to close it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685287/debugging-in-dev-c-makes-ide-crash-and-not-respond#:~:text=%20%20%201%20Open%20File%20-%3E%20New,line%20you%20want%20and%20debug%20it.%20More%20 Check this post probably gonna help you with this issue mate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging in Dev-C++ makes IDE crash and not respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685287/debugging-in-dev-c-makes-ide-crash-and-not-respond)